# AND / OR service dependencies in Icinga / Nagios

Tags: nagios, icinga

I've been setting up an Icinga instance using service dependencies as so:

```
define servicedependency{
    dependent_host_name                             ahost
    dependent_service_description                   Battery Time
    host_name                                       powerware1
    service_description                             UPS Input 1 Voltage
    notification_failure_criteria   o
}
define servicedependency{
    dependent_host_name                             ahost
    dependent_service_description                   Battery Time
    host_name                                       powerware1
    service_description                             UPS Input 2 Voltage
    notification_failure_criteria   o
}
```

These work, but suppress the alerts for "Battery Time" if *either* of the inputs is working. How can I adjust this so it suppresses only if *both* of the inputs are working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a meta-service that uses `check_multi` (or `check_cluster`) to check both of the voltage check services, and use that for the service dependency.